# How to delete specific elements from an array in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I dont know the numbers which are stored in the array[multidimensional].As I get these numbers from the sensor.I just know that If the same number is repeated more than 5 times, that number should be deleted.
please help.

Comment: Once created, arrays are of fixed size. You either have to set the value to an "invalid" value (v.g., -1 if all correct values are positive) or create a new array deleting the elements (but it sheldom will be regular enough to use a multidimensional array). Check also for *arrays of arrays* (which is not the same than multidimensional array).

Comment: You do not know the numbers? I do not really understand. Just print them on the screen to see them. Then you have to be aware that "the same number" is a bit tricky with `float`s or `double`s. Do not check for equality (`a==b`) but use some reasonable bound (i.e. `abs(a-b)<eps`). And btw we can only help you if you show us some code or explain better what you did and where you got stuck.

Comment: thanks sjuan76 , but this does not answer my question.

Comment: You didnt ask any question...

Answer (score 0):

> How to delete specific elements from an array

Depends on what do you mean by "delete". An array of `x` numbers always has exactly `x` numbers. An integer can't have a state that represents a "deleted" number, unless you decide that a specific value signifies such state. A typical choice would be `-1` if only positive values are used otherwise. A floating point number could be set to NaN, but considering the "repeated 5 times" requirement, remember that equality comparison of floating point numbers is not trivial.

Or, you could maintain a duplicate array of bools which signifies whether the number in corresponding index has been deleted.

Another approach would be to augment your array with a pointer to the last "used" number (or rather, point to the one after the last used number). This allows you to represent a smaller (dynamic)array than fits into the whole array. The size of such dynamic array would be the distance between address of the first number and the pointer and the size may change up to `x`. The numbers beyond the pointer would then be considered deleted. You must take care not to access the deleted numbers thinking they would contain valid data. If you want to delete a number in middle of the array, simply copy all numbers after it one index to the left and decrement the pointer. If you don't want to implement this yourself (and you shouldn't want to), you may want to use `std::vector` instead since this is pretty much what vector does under the hood.